# reallocating struct causes heap corruption

Tags: c, visual-studio, struct, heap-memory

I'm writing a program in C that creates and tries to allocate the struct array. It manages to allocate the first block of memory and i successfully wrote the values on it but when i try to allocate a second time i get a error related to corrupted heap and "Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap".

here is my code (sorry for some parts in portuguese):

**structs.h:**

```
typedef struct vendedor
{
    unsigned int numero; 
    char *       nome;
    float        salario;
    uint8_t      comissao;
} VENDEDOR;
```

**functions.h**

```
extern vendedor     * vende = (vendedor *)malloc(0);
extern unsigned int vende_sz = 0;

char * receberString()
{
    int size = 0;
    char temporary;
    char * string = NULL;

    string = (char *)malloc(size);

    while (true)
    {
        scanf("%c", &temporary);

        string = (char *)realloc(string, (size + 1) * sizeof(char));

        if (temporary == '\n')
        {
            string[size] = '\0';
            return string;
        }
        else
            string[size] = temporary;

        size++;
    }
}

vendedor * alocarVende()
{
    vendedor * tmpVende = (vendedor *)
        realloc(vende, sizeof(vendedor)* vende_sz+1); //crashes here at second time

    if (tmpVende == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nfailed to allocate.\n");
        //free(tmpVende);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        vende = tmpVende;
        //commented due to problems related
        //free(tmpVende);
        vende_sz++;
        return vende;
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "structs.h"
#include "functions.h"

int main() {
    login();
    return 0;
}

bool login() 
{
    if (vende_sz == 0)
    {
        vende = alocarVende();

        vende[0].salario = 666.66;
        vende[0].numero = 1;
        vende[0].comissao = 22;

        vende[0].nome = receberString(); //dynamically allocates memory for a string using realloc
        printf("%s", vende[0].nome);

        vende = alocarVende();

        vende[1].nome = receberString(); //dynamically allocates memory for a string using realloc
        printf("%s", vende[1].nome);

        return true;
    }
}
```

any tips or help? I tried commenting free and some other things but still the same problem, thanks.

Edit: added more bits of code.

Comment: `vende = tmpVende; free(tmpVende);` <----- this.

Comment: `typedef struct`, `malloc` & `free`, you might have a .cpp file but this is not c++.

Comment: I'm writing the code in C but i was forced to use visual studio. Compiling with gcc results the same problem.

Comment: You don't need a `free()` for each pointer variable, you need one for each allocation (when fully done with it).  If two pointers point to the same allocated block, you only free it once -- when you're done with both pointers.

Comment: @GabrielAC17 I'm referring to the fact that you had tagged the question with [tag:c++]

Comment: Oh, sorry for that, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C! And don't put (function) definitions (except for `inline` functions) into headers! Please read what headers are for before writing your own.

Comment: If you go to http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ you can write *everything* in Portuguese. Just so you know :)

Comment: @Olaf thanks for advice, will remember that from now on.

Comment: @Laurel didn't knew there was a portuguese one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    vende = tmpVende;
    free(tmpVende);
```

This is precisely the same as:

```
    vende = tmpVende;
    free(vende);
```

Since `vede` and `tmpVende` are pointers with the same value, passing either one to `free` does the same thing -- frees the underlying thing they both point to.

```
vende[1].nome = receberString();
```

Thus this is a use after free that corrupts memory.

Also, you have this:

```
sizeof(vendedor)* vende_sz+1
```

Which doesn't do what you want because multiplication has higher precedence than addition.

Comment: Ok, i got that part but it still stops at line:
    "void* const new_block = HeapReAlloc(__acrt_heap, 0, block, size);" in realloc_base.cpp

Comment: That's a typical error caused by a use after free bug. As I showed, `vende[1].nome = receberString();` is a use after free. (See update.)

Comment: I understanded it and removed the free's before returning (pretty sure there isn't a free anywhere now) but still get the same stop at that line above.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if you had more than one bug. Give us enough code to reproduce the error.

Comment: You have `sizeof(vendedor)* vende_sz+1` but you want `sizeof(vendedor)* (vende_sz+1)`! (See updates.)

Comment: Oh, missed that one too, thanks for helping but i'm still having problems at the same point, now he triggers a breakpoint at     "return HeapValidate(__acrt_heap, 0, header_from_block(block));
}" with "HEAP[Petshop.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 012C0000, 012D8930 )"